# Помогите разобраться в виджете datapicker!

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код
`$("#datepicker1,#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
      showWeek: true,
      firstDay: 1
  });`
Есть форма состоящая из 2 полей в одном нужно выбрать дату приезда(#datapicker1) в другом  отьезда(#datapicker2).При выборе даты в одном из полей дата появляеться сразу на обоих полях.Мне нужно что бы в каждом поле я мог отдельную дату ставить.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828440/multiple-datepicker-in-same-page-not-working-javascript
id, name самих полей. И инициализация немного иначе выполняется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `datepicker` создаёт один экземпляр виджета на выбранных полях. Создайте два. Один для одного поля и один для второго.